# Unpivot Table SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, unpivot

I've read a few posts and could not come up with a solution.

I have the following answers table. ID 184 will have an unknown number of entries, so hard-coding each amount and name is not an option.

`ID       TEXT      TAG    ORD
 184      Halifax   Bnk     1
 184      RBS       Bnk     2
 184      Natwest   Bnk     3
 184      32.16     Amt     1
 184      80.15     Amt     2
 184      62.54     Amt     3`

I need the following output based on TAG and ORD I need to list Bank & Amount.

`Bank      Amount
 Halifax    32.16
 RBS        80.15
 Natwest    62.54`

My code so far...

```
select *  
from 
(select
f.id as "ID"
,a.text as "01TEXT"
,a.tag as  "02TAG"
,a.ord as "03ORD"
from
freq f

left join answers a
on a.freq_id = f.id and a.tag in ('Bnk','Amt')

where
f.id = 184
)unpivot (amount for tag in ("03ORD"))
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks
Genzz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to `UNPIVOT` that data.  You need to `PIVOT` it.  This gives you the results you are asking for:

```
with test_data as (
SELECT 184 ID,     'Halifax' text,   'Bnk' tag,     1 ord from dual union all
SELECT 184 ID,     'RBS' text,   'Bnk' tag,     2 ord from dual union all
SELECT 184 ID,     'Natwest' text,   'Bnk' tag,     3 ord from dual union all
SELECT 184 ID,     '32.16' text,   'Amt' tag,     1 ord from dual union all
SELECT 184 ID,     '80.15' text,   'Amt' tag,     2 ord from dual union all
SELECT 184 ID,     '62.54' text,   'Amt' tag,     3 ord from dual
)
select bank_name, amount from test_data
pivot ( max(text) for tag in ('Bnk' as bank_name, 'Amt' as amount) )
order by ord
```

Only the last 3 lines are of interest to you.  The `test_data` SQL is just to give a working example without having access to your tables.

Comment: Did you read my response?  I "hardcoded" the entries in `test_data` to give me data for the query.  They're not part of the solution.  The actual solution only hardcodes the values in the `tag` field.

Comment: Thank you Matthew. That works, I now need to work around the LONG data_type for the TEXT column.

Answer (score 1):

here is another way

```
select

f.text  as "Bank"
,a.text as "Amount"
from  answers f
left join answers a
on a.id = f.id 
and a.tag ='Amt'
and a.ord = f.ord

where
f.id = 184
and f.tag = 'Bnk'
```